# Convert a String of hex to an Int

Tags: swift, numbers, int, hex

I'm working in Swift and I have this string as input: `"0x13123ac"` 
And I want an `Int` as output: `0x13123ac`

How can I do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45667905/3908884

Comment: [This SwiftRadix](https://github.com/orchetect/SwiftRadix) is helpful

Answer (score 11):

Your question makes no sense. Computers store numbers in binary, not hex. Perhaps what you wanted was to convert a hex string to an integer and convert it back to hex for display purposes:

```
let input = "0x13123ac"

// Int(_, radix: ) can't deal with the '0x' prefix. NSScanner can handle hex
// with or without the '0x' prefix
let scanner = Scanner(string: input)
var value: UInt64 = 0

if scanner.scanHexInt64(&value) {
    print("Decimal: \(value)")
    print("Hex: 0x\(String(value, radix: 16))")
}
```