# Convert Hexa to Decimal in Swift

Tags: swift, hex, decimal

I want to convert Hexa value into decimal. So I have tried this. When value is >0, then it is working fine. But when value is <0, then is returns wrong value.

```
let h2 = “0373”
let d4 = Int(h2, radix: 16)!
print(d4) // 883

let h3 = “FF88”
let d5 = Int(h3, radix: 16)!
print(d5) // 65416
```

When I am passing FF88, then it returns 65416. But actually it is -120.

Right now, I am following this [Convert between Decimal, Binary and Hexadecimal in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36967037/3908884) answer. But it didn't works always.

Please check this conversation [online](http://www.scadacore.com/field-tools/programming-calculators/online-hex-converter/). Please see following image for more details of this conversation.

[image]

Is there any other solution for get minus decimal from Hexa value.?

Any help would be appreciated !!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`FF 88` is the hexadecimal representation of the *16-bit signed* integer
`-120`. You can create an unsigned integer first and then convert it
to the signed counterpart with the same bit pattern:

```
let h3 = "FF88"
let u3 = UInt16(h3, radix: 16)!  // 65416
let s3 = Int16(bitPattern: u3)   // -120
```

Comment: The title says "Convert Hexa to **Decimal** in Swift"
How is  UInt16 or  Int16 considered a Decimal ?

Comment: @iOSBlacksmith: As I understand it from the question, “decimal” here does not refer to the Swift `Decimal` type, but just means an integer (which, when printed, shows the base-10 representation of that number).

Answer (score 1):

Hexadecimal conversion depends on integer Type ( `signed , unsigned` ) and size ( `64 bits , 32 bits , 16 bits . .`  ) , this is what you missed .

**source code :**

```
let h3 = "FF88"
let d5 = Int16(truncatingBitPattern: strtoul(h3, nil, 16))
print(d5) // -120
```